# wget: automatically overwrite dowloaded file create time to current?

Tags: bash, wget

When I download file using wget it copies create time from original file on server by default:

```
> wget https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ByEt7bVIQAAzDVq.jpg
> ls -l  ByEt7bVIQAAzDVq.jpg
-rw------- 1 d9k d9k 20K Sep 21  2014 ByEt7bVIQAAzDVq.jpg
```

How automatically overwrite dowloaded file time to current without using `touch` after each download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [`man wget`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/wget.1.html) explains:

```
       --no-use-server-timestamps
           Don't set the local file's timestamp by the one on the server.

           By default, when a file is downloaded, its timestamps are set to
           match those from the remote file. This allows the use of
           --timestamping on subsequent invocations of wget. However, it is
           sometimes useful to base the local file's timestamp on when it was
           actually downloaded; for that purpose, the
           --no-use-server-timestamps option has been provided.
```

That is, to make the timestamp on the downloaded file represent when it was created on the local machine, use the `--no-use-server-timestamps` flag:

```
ek@Io:~$ wget https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ByEt7bVIQAAzDVq.jpg --no-use-server-timestamps
--2015-04-05 00:04:55--  https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ByEt7bVIQAAzDVq.jpg
Resolving pbs.twimg.com (pbs.twimg.com)... 199.96.57.7
Connecting to pbs.twimg.com (pbs.twimg.com)|199.96.57.7|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 19846 (19K) [image/jpeg]
Saving to: ‘ByEt7bVIQAAzDVq.jpg’

ByEt7bVIQAAzDVq.jpg 100%[=====================>]  19.38K  --.-KB/s   in 0.04s  

2015-04-05 00:04:56 (538 KB/s) - ‘ByEt7bVIQAAzDVq.jpg’ saved [19846/19846]

ek@Io:~$ ls -l ByEt7bVIQAAzDVq.jpg 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ek ek 19846 Apr  5 00:04 ByEt7bVIQAAzDVq.jpg
```

The advantage of the default behavior, as explained in the manpage, is in case you later want to retrieve the file again, automatically downloading it only if a newer one is available.

Answer (score 2):

Found it:

```
% wget --no-use-server-timestamps https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ByEt7bVIQAAzDVq.jpg
% ls -l  ByEt7bVIQAAzDVq.jpg
-rw------- 1 d9k d9k 19846 Apr  5 07:02 ByEt7bVIQAAzDVq.jpg
```